# Highlight Cells Based on If Function

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a VBA code or excel function which can highlight the A cell based on the value of the corresponding B cell. For example if the number in row A is larger than B then highlight the A cell green and orange if B is larger. As shown

[image]

Is there some option to do this in conditional formatting? Or even a VBA code?

Comment: Trye [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-conditional-formatting).  Take a look at the default options and there're a few that support this specific case.l

Answer (score 2):

Add something like this using conditional formatting:

[image: Demo]

^ `=A1<A2` and `=A1>A2`.

And then select the Format Painter and drag it along:

[image: Demo2]

Answer (score 0):

No need manual formatting. Just use full range containing data in `Apply To` section.

As per your screenshot.

1. Select `B1:G2` cells.
2. Select `Conditional Formatting` under style section. Then click on `New Rule`.
   [image]
3. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

[image]

4. Use formula like below screenshot.

   `=B1<B$2`

   `=B1>B$2`

[image]

> Result

[image]